# How can I specify the package when instantiating a class?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have many classes with the same name in different packages. Take the following directory structure as an example:

[image]

From within the constructor of the templates/Person class, how can I declare an instance of rules/Person?

The code I expected to work (but has an error on line 10) is as follows:

```
from Template import Template
import rules


class Person(Template):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Person, self).__init__('Person')
    self.rules = [
      rules.Person() #this is an error
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PEP328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports) has the answer, I think.

```
from .myfolder import Template as Template
from .myfolder1 import Template as Template1
from .myfolder2 import Template as Template2
from pip_installed_library1 import Template as Template3
from pip_installed_library2 import Template as Template4
```

Using this pattern they never share names.